# mySQL aggregate query with hireachy

Tags: mysql

Article Table:

```
ID | INT(10)
Category | INT(10)
```

Category Table:

```
ID | INT(10)
Parent | INT(10)
```

What I want to generate is a tree that includes a count of articles at all levels e.g.

```
A (30)
--> B (20)
--> --> C (10)
--> --> D (10)
--> --> --> Q (6)
--> --> --> L (4)
--> E (5)
--> F (5)
G (8)
--> H (8)
--> --> I (7)
--> --> J (1)
```

I'd really like to be able to generate this output in a single SQL query; however I can do anything to the database structure if that helped. At the moment the only way we can see to do this is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles GROUP BY category
```

and then create the hireachy in code. That's what we are trying to avoid.

The only other approach I can think of is a complicated IF() statement which is auto generated based on a pre-computed list of ID hierachies.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

The one query is a `SELECT` that fetches everything, then your application code does all the formatting work.

Or you make a messy Stored Procedure to do all that work.  And you spend longer than you would like debugging it.